# Powershell write to console

Tags: powershell, console

I am trying to Write the number of error and a message on the console. I am using the following code:

```
    $dir = "d:\logs\prov\"
    $latest = Get-ChildItem -PAth $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending |      Select-Object -First 1
    $eCounter = get-content $dir$latest | select-string "ERROR"
    $eCounter.Count
    $eText = "There are " + $eCounter.Count + " errors returned"

    if ($eCounter.count -gt 0)
    {
      $eCounter.Count
      $eText    
    }
```

As the code suggests, it looks into a folder to find the latest log file, count the number of "ERROR" entries, and write it to the console with a message. The problem is that the result is writing three lines (as follows) instead of two. The number is writing twice for some reason that I cannot figure out. I need it to write once.

5

5

There are 5 errors returned

Comment: Maybe I was too hard on the OP, but I downvoted for the following reasons: The questions shows little to no effort. The number is posted 3 times, and what is the only line used in three seperate locations? http://stackoverflow.com/tour is pretty clear that you should not ask questions without showing what you have tried yourself. In a small (<10 lines) script like this, the OP should have a clear idea as to what went wrong. The question is also very specific to OP's situation and will be hard to reuse.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty clear to be honest...

```
$dir = "d:\logs\prov\"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -PAth $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending |      Select-Object -First 1
$eCounter = get-content $dir$latest | select-string "ERROR"

### LINE 1 (Number only)
$eCounter.Count

$eText = "There are " + $eCounter.Count + " errors returned"

if ($eCounter.count -gt 0)
{
### LINE 2 (Number only)
    $eCounter.Count
### LINE 3 (Full text)      
    $eText    
}
```

If you only want the line "There are ... errors returned", then remove both `$eCounter.count` lines.

Answer (score -2):

Change the line $eText to the following and see if the result changes:

```
$eText = "There are " + [string]$eCounter.Count + " errors returned"
```

The problem is the count is an integer so it can't be appended properly to the string

Comment: Yah good call. I was wrong anyways with what I said. Upvoted you